# Build and run project that use math.h in Clion

Tags: clion

How do I add flags like `-lm`(for math.h) in Clion to build and run a c file?

I basically want to use `pow()` function from `math.h` in my code and run and debug the same in Clion.

I'm new to CMake.
This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Assign2)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
add_executable(Assign2 ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: What have you tried? What did you find? What's the error? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have edited the question to pinpoint my objective.

Comment: I did see that link. But didn't understand fully. Can you please explain it there, then I can delete this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `target_link_libraries(YOUR_TARGET_NAME_HERE m)` to your `CMakeLists.txt` file.

(If you've tried that, or don't know what's the name of your target, please add the contents of your `CMakeLists.txt` file to your question)

---

Edit: your target name is `Assign2`, so at the bottom of your `CMakeLists.txt`, you need to add:

```
target_link_libraries(Assign2 m)
```

Comment: I have edited Question accordingly

Comment: What's TARGET_NAME?

Comment: It's Assign2, I just edited my answer. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html