# Calculate the abs value of a complex in C

Tags: c, linker-errors, clion

Part of the source code:

```
double _Complex z = 1.0 + 1.0*I;
printf("%f\n", cabs(z));
```

My development environment: *Ubuntu16.04LTS, Clion IDE with GCC version 5.4.0, C11 standard*.

As I run the code, an error occurs with message

```
undefined reference to `cabs'
```

The IDE tells me that the function `cabs` is declared in the header file `cmathcalls.h`, so I try to:

```
#include<cmathcalls.h>
```

But the IDE warns me that the file cannot be found, so again I try:

```
#include<bits/cmathcalls>
```

The I run the code, however it still doesn't work.

I want to know how can I get the abs value of the complex `z` with the function `cabs`?

Comment: try `gcc file.c -lm`

Comment: You write: _"As I run the code..."_. Do you rather mean _"when I compile the code..."_?

Comment: You should really have a closer look on the messages of compiler, linker etc. that your IDE hopefully displays somewhere. Here you can see *what exactly* fails. Simply hitting [Run] sometimes includes a build of the program.

Comment: did you add the library to `CMakeLists.txt`?
`target_link_libraries(<target> m)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `cabs` you just need [`<complex.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/cabs.html). Where it is actually declared is just an implementation detail.

And then link with `-lm` to actually link the math library in.

Comment: I use the command line to compile my code,with '-lm'added,it works.But can I make it work using the IDE?

Comment: @罗通侯君 - Follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39150697/build-and-run-project-that-use-math-h-in-clion).